# What is the Benghazi controversy?

Tags: united-states, embassy, libya, state-department

Recently, I've been hearing bits and pieces regarding some controversy involving the [2012 Benghazi embassy attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Benghazi_attack#Criticism_of_U.S._government_response)

Although It's not hard to find stories about the controversy , I've found it considerably harder to find out exactly what the controversy is starting from the beginning.

- What is the Benghazi controversy?
- What about it draws so much coverage?
- Why is it making such major news now?

Comment: There will be many books that will discuss this by the time it ends I think.  There fore this question is way to broad for this SE.

Comment: @Chad  Too Broad?  It's a question about a scandal revolving around a very specific event.  I'd hardly call it too broad.

Comment: There could and probably will be books written about this very question, what happened, why, what caused the news orgs to ignore then pick up the story...  I think that there is already one book either about to be released or that has been released from the security team that went in to clean up after

Comment: @Chad So what??

Comment: It's absolutely a broad question. TOO broad? I dunno. But we certainly don't have the facts to state what the scandal actually was. A this time, it's still mostly speculation and punditry.

Comment: @blip I don't think we have the facts to state what *happened* but we can state what the *scandal is*, or rather, why it is scandalous.

Comment: @ThePompitousofLove at best it's a perceived scandal. We know a bit more now than 3 years ago when I left that comment. With hindsight, it was mostly a perceived scandal.

Comment: Your question is meiopic and lacks forethought. western nations have no valid moral or ethical reason to attack, occupy, and rob a sovereign Arab country and murder its leader.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On September 11, 2012, There was an attack on the United-States Embassy in Behghazi.  4 people died in this attack.

It was initially believed by the public that this attack was in response to the movie ["Innocence of Muslims"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocence_of_Muslims).

Several days later, It was confirmed to be a terrorist attack that was related to Al Qaeda.

---

The accusation is that the Obama Administration knew that it was a terrorist attack, and that they initially tried to cover it up.  They are also being accused of not reacting strongly enough to the attacks, and not being prepared enough for such attacks.

On May 8 -

> Gregory Hicks, Eric Nordstrom, and Mark Thompson testify before the United States House Committee on Oversight and Government Reform, and were called "whistleblowers" by the committee chairman.
>
> Hicks testified that more assistance from the U.S. military could have been provided, that attempts to send additional forces were told to stand down by another authority, and he was demoted for telling his recollection of events; the Defense Department disputed Hicks' testimony, and the State Department did not respond.
>
> Hicks further stated that since the Libyan government had called the attack a terrorist attack, and the United States did not, complicated the FBI investigation.  Thompson testified that a Foreign Emergency Support Team was not sent due to instructions from the State Department, which the State Department said would have taken too long to be effective;
>
> Nordstrom criticized the Accountability Review Board, that it did not look into decisions made by those individuals in higher authority.  Furthermore, they testified that their previous attempts to increase security leading up to the attacks were, were denied.
>
> Democrats charged that the Republicans were politicizing the investigation.

---

> House Republicans released a report on the Benghazi attack that was
> highly critical of the White House and the State Department; the White
> House dismissed the report, and House Democrats called the report
> biased.[128]
>
> Among dozens of findings, the report[129] states that:
>
> - "Senior State Department officials knew that the threat environment in Benghazi was high and that the Benghazi compound was
>   vulnerable and unable to withstand an attack, yet the department
>   continued to systematically withdraw security personnel"
> - The "[Obama] Administration willfully perpetuated a deliberately misleading and incomplete narrative that the attacks evolved from a
>   political demonstration caused by a YouTube video."
> - "... after a White House Deputies Meeting on Saturday, September 15, 2012, the Administration altered the talking points to remove
>   references to the likely participation of Islamic extremists in the
>   attacks. The Administration also removed references to the threat of
>   extremists linked to al-Qa’ida in Benghazi and eastern Libya...."
> - "The Administration deflected responsibility by blaming the IC [intelligence community] for the information it communicated to the
>   public in both the talking points and the subsequent narrative it
>   perpetuated."

---

sources:

["2012 Benghazi attack" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Benghazi_attack)

["Timeline of the investigation into the 2012 Benghazi attack" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_investigation_into_the_2012_Benghazi_attack)

Comment: Also the fact that four Americans - including the Ambassador which is supposed to be the person representing US in this country - were killed also makes the matter very serious. If the attack were deflected with no casualties I think the matter would get, even with the same alleged failures, less attention.

Comment: Also, you may want to add a point that a part of the scandal was the [unprecedented act of jailing of the movie producer](http://www.mediaite.com/tv/innocence-of-muslims-filmmaker-speaks-to-fox-from-prison-if-i-could-go-back-id-release-video-again/) as part of the government's reactions.

Comment: This clearly outlines part of the complaint. But that doesn't necessarily define the scandal. It's not a bad answer, but not sure it meshes with the wording of the original question.

Comment: @StasM the thing is that there were many more attacks and deaths upon embassies under the previous president, so I don't think there's a direct correlation to number of deaths and media attention.

Comment: @DA This is not true, no ambassadors were killed on duty under the previous president. See the list of ambassadors killed in office: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassadors_of_the_United_States#Ambassadors_killed_in_office 
The death of the ambassador is an exceptional event, as it is a direct attack on a sovereignty of the represented country. It is always a huge deal.

Comment: @StasM that statement is true. There were more attacks on, and deaths at US embassies under the previous president: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrorist_attacks_on_U.S._diplomatic_facilities However, in terms of Ambassadors only, you are correct.

Comment: Recommend modifying your second line to "The public was initially told that..."

Comment: @DrunkCynic why would you recommend that?

Comment: @user4012 your comment sounds as if he was arrested for being the movie producer, while he was arrested for violating his parole terms... or are you suggesting that he should have get immunity because he was the producer of such a film? Roman Polansky is interested in that idea and wants to subscribe to your e-letter.

Comment: @SamIam How was the public led to believe the video was responsible for the violence?

Comment: @SamIam  think that it would be a better answer would include information about why its important (Hillary Clinton is running for Pres.) This is  a good answer, though. I don't get why we are voting on closing it.

Comment: @DrunkCynic I was a member of the public at the time, and the reason why **I** believed it was a protest to the movie, was because there was a notable protest in Egypt around that same time, which really was about the movie.

Comment: "It was initially believed by the public that this attack was in response to the movie Innocence of Muslims"

More specifically, it was initially **claimed by the administration** that the attack was in response to a movie.  This claim was later shown to be false -- then-Secretary of State Hillary Clinton lied to the American People.

Comment: You may want to add that Obama flew to a fundraiser the next morning after the attack, a theme in his presidency https://www.cnsnews.com/news/article/zoey-dimauro/during-times-crisis-president-obama-goes-golfing-fundraising

Answer (score 1):

> What is the Benghazi scandal?

Official statements at the time didn't entirely mesh with what happened. The scandal part is the theory is that there may have been a cover up of some sort.

> What about it makes it such a big scandal?

A matter of opinion.

> Why is it making such major news now?

Those with the opinion that it's a scandal have been using it as a frequent enough talking point as to keep it in the media spotlight.

Comment: that answer hardly answered my question at all.

Comment: @SamIam while the details of the 'scandal' are many, the overall issue is fairly straight forward. The administration's statements didn't align with the actions. Wikipedia has a decent synopsis of all the investigations' conclusions thus far: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Benghazi_attack#Investigation

Comment: +1 That's a pretty good summary.  People are working themselves up over whether or not this was recognized as a terror attack right away, like it really matters in the long run.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - it's seen as a major proof of a long running  administration policy viewpoint and posture (pretending that the real "extremists" are Tea Party and that Jihadism is not an active threat)

Comment: @DVK, I would say it's seen that way by a small number of people who seem quite desperate to make that a legitimate talking point when statistically speaking, the current level of Jihadism is *not* a threat to the average first-worlder.  You may make a case that the attack was downplayed by the current administration, I don't think there's anyone who can legitimately argue with you on that; likewise when it became  a political liability to be downplaying this the administration reversed course.  Attaching something sinister to everyday politics makes mountains out of molehills.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs - statistically speaking, the current level of mass murdering spree is even less of a threat to an average American. Nevertheless, one isolated attack was all the excuse that was necessary to have a bunch of people try to object to the Second Amendment, despite the fact that most of the proposed solutions would not have addressed the incident that was used as the excuse.

Comment: "it's seen as a major proof" = well, that goes to point #2 of my answer in that it's a matter of opinion. Whether or not it is--or rather, how big or small of--a scandal this is is very much a matter of opinion at this point. Maybe we'll know more in a month, maybe not.

Comment: @DVK ...agreed 100% on that.  That too was blown out of proportion, but since it seems popular the administration is sticking with it.  If the president had decided to let cooler heads prevail on that as well perhaps that too would be considered a "scandal"...

Comment: This site certainly has a particular slant. It's becoming much less interesting of a place to hang out at.

Answer (score -4):

I'm going to give you a very simple, two minute response.

What is the Benghazi scandal?

A US Diplomatic building came under attack by Libyan protesters. Three Americans(including the US Ambassador to Libya) died.

What about it draws so much coverage?

It's a combination of things. The Obama Administration did not handle the situation very well, not claiming it was a really big issue, not using specific terms, etc. But the reason it draws so much coverage is the fact that Media needs drama. Fox News, NBC, etc.

Why is it making such major news now?
Various Conservative Representatives and Media Outlets are making a big deal out of the situation. They always have.

Comment: -1 - Doesn't describe the situation at all and then dismisses the entire scandal as being nothing more than being some trumped up conspiracy with no evidence to back up that claim. The evidence clearly shows that there are legitimate questions that the white house administration and state department refuse to answer. This refusal to be open and forthcoming by the administration only lends credibility to the idea that there really was some wrong doing here. Otherwise, it would be very easy to make this entire story go away by providing simple answers to simple questions.

Comment: Allegation that US government lied and neglected to protect US embassy for political reasons are way beyond "media needs drama". Whatever is your opinion on the veracity of such allegations, it's not simply media-invented story, there are serious causes for concern and investigation, which are proved by ample evidence.

Comment: "The evidence clearly shows" = what 'evidence' we have is sparse. The 'scandal' at this time, is more hyperbole than it is fact-based data. Maybe that will change with time. Maybe not.

Comment: @DA:However, what evidence we do have raises very legitimate questions. The more "evidence" that keeps getting discovered the more legitimate questions that keep arising. Funny how that tends to happen when a coverup is in progress. Openness and honesty tend to quell further questions.

Comment: @Dunk I think it certainly raises valid questions. And they are important questions. But it's important to distinguish between questions being asked and what actually happened. It appears Sam was asking what *it is* but most of our answers are *what some think it may be*.

Answer (score -8):

Sorry that I don't have references but here's what I can recall from the various reports I've heard, seen or read.

"What is the Benghazi scandal"

It's that the administration is refusing to disclose what really happened. Who made what decisions and when? They've intimidated state dept./CIA employees into keeping silent. What was removed from the original report before the one that was officially released? Who removed those details? There's just too much evasion (or appearance of evasion) if there really is nothing of interest to be found.

Even if everything done by the WH administration was perfectly valid, the mere fact that the Obama administration doesn't believe there is any obligation to answer to the people/congress is arrogant and deserving of whatever scrutiny is thrown at them. Why would it have been so hard for Hillary to simply state what she did and didn't do on the night in question? Instead, she acted like a spoiled brat who was insulted that congress had the gaul to inquire into finding out what happened on that night. Especially, when it is so obvious that many details were being left out in the official explanation.

Nobody has ever gotten an answer to where was Obama and what did he know while all this was happening. Obama is notorious for his dislike of meetings so he chooses to get his security info via email-like reports instead. Some believe that he got the report but didn't bother reading it, so he didn't even know Benghazi was happening.

"What makes it a big scandal"

One theory is that the WH admin chose to not defend the embassy because the voters seeing terrorist activity at that time might cost Obama some votes. So the WH chose to let people die instead. Although, in fairness it was probably more like they chose to leave people in a dangerous situation and it blew up in their faces when people were actually killed. Was the WH willing to endanger lives for the sake of their election? How high up did this decision go?

Another possibility, from above is how "engaged" in doing his job is Obama really. Did he get the security report? Did he read it? Did he do anything about it?

Another issue is the administration intimidating employees into not talking to congress. You can't have checks and balances if people are intimidated into silence.

"Why is it making major news now"

Because congress finally found a couple of people willing to talk. After their testimony, the WH has now gone on to rev. 4 or 5 of their version of what happened. Sorry, I don't remember which WH official testified after Hicks last week but I remember him saying something like what follows that I believe will become infamous "It is not the State Departments job to ...[ughhh can't remember]". But it was kind of an admission that they knew more than they've already admitted to knowing.

Anyways, while the MSM is trying to sweep this story under the carpet, you can see that there's all kinds of side stories and theories that actually make this quite an interesting investigation. Many of the pundits strongly believe that this story is going to take some big-shot down, but nobody knows who yet.

Comment: There's a lot of opinion, wild speculation and bias in this answer.

Comment: The OP asked why this is a big story. Nobody else provided any answer that even gave an inkling as to why this is such a big story. The above answer most certainly describes some of the reasons why this story is receiving attention. I agree that references would be nice, but I do this for fun and not for writing a term paper. That's why I generally don't post an "answer" unless nobody has given a decent answer for a couple of days. The alternative is for people to ask questions and never receive a response that actually answers their question. Speculation is part of why this is a big story.

Comment: @DA:I would also add that your answer is also biased. Yours is just done in a passive-aggressive way.

Comment: no passive aggressiveness was intended. I was simply trying to distill down the issue sans commentary. That said, I think your answer backs up mine--what makes it a 'big' scandals is a matter of opinion. In your opinion, it appears to be a big scandal.

Comment: @DA:Much of what I wrote isn't necessarily "my opinion" but what I've heard/read others say on the topic. The goal was to describe why many people believe that there really is a story worth covering here so the OP can get enough of a taste to decide if its worth their time to follow. Plus, writing in a neutral tone would leave one underwhelmed. It's the theatrics and color that make the story interesting. Just saying "it's a matter of opinion" is dismissive, which is the passive-aggressive part. Plus, it doesn't provide any info for the OP to even begin to get a handle on the topic.

Comment: "It's the theatrics and color that make the story interesting" = I agree totally. And I feel that color punditry is very much part of politics. That said, on StackExchange sites, we're encouraged to not use that model for answers.

Comment: @DA:Well it may not be encouraged to use that model for answers, but until more people are willing to speak out, that is a large part of what makes this particular scandal an interesting story and why the media has latched onto it. Any answer that doesn't include it, isn't answering the question that was asked.

Comment: This answer has alot of claims of fact but no refrerences.  It is there for not an answer by SE Standards.

Comment: I've accepted this question as the answer because it is more or less consistent with other things that I've heard so far.  There was a planned terrorist attack on the embassy in Benghazi last year.  The White house didn't acknowledge that it was a planned terrorist attack immediately, and apparently people think there's some coverup mixed up in there too.  So until someone comes up with a better answer, This will remain marked

Comment: @Chad  This is politics, not history.  This question was more or less "What is it that people are concerned about"  Whether or not the scandal itself has valid basis need not be part of the answer

Comment: @SamIam - Then that is what the question should be but as it stands the question is "what is the scandal..."  That is actually a better question than what you originally posed IMO

Comment: @Chad That's practically the definition of a scandal

Comment: @SamIam if you're not concerned about the validity of it, then I'd suggest rewording the question to 'alleged scandal'.